# VS Code dart line format, lines go to new line after center of the screen

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

When the code reaches the center of the screen, the dart formator goes to a new line even when I don't want it to. This creates awkward lines like the picture below. How can I change this? This. only happens at the center of the screen.

[image]

Comment: @h8moss Yes, it does. Thank you